# Why is the black star filled with a human soul so expensive?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to minimize cost when I enchant and I've already lost 2 daedric items because I believe I didn't use the proper gem. Most likely I use the black star or a grand soul gem filled with a grand soul but most likely I'm looking at the price of the gem. A grand soul gem filled with a petty soul is pretty affordable. My situation is that I have 2 steel armor with a 17,5% more enchantment then on the daedric armor. Hence looking at the price of the black star it is usually 1000 septimes but a grand soul is 500 septimes.

Is the black star better filled? Is there are better bigger soul then grand soul gem filled with a grand soul worth a 500 septimes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are mixing up Black Star and Black Soul Gem.

[Black Star](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Black_Star) is a reuseable Black Soul Gem, which you get from a quest, where you can choose Azura's Star or the Black Star.

Black Soul Gems differ from Grand Soul Gems in that they can contain human souls (which ordinary soulgems can't).

Answer (score 2):

The reason the Black Star is valued at 1000g compared to the Grand Soul Gems 500g is due to the fact that the Black Star is a Daedric Artifact given as a quest reward. It's a one of a kind item, whereas Grand Soul Gems are about as common as those wooden plates you accidentally pick up when trying to grab a few loose septims lying on a table.

Also, the Black Star can capture human souls. Grand Soul Gems cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Every human soul (aka Black Soul) is grand by default. Under these circumstances the Black Star is a great item.
And this is why the filled Black Star is so expensive: it contains a grand soul.